# Intel Crosswalk versus Adobe AIR : runtime download size

Tags: air, crosswalk-runtime

With the intention of normalizing behavior across various browser O/S levels, Intel offers the Crosswalk HTML5 "runtime".

Adobe offers an option where the AIR runtime is bundled up or embedded as part of the mobile app deployment package.

How large are these two runtimes?

Comment: With nothing in the app but a basic little vector animation, air for android .apk is 10.3mb and air for ios .ipa is 6.9mb.  Can't help with crosswalk.

Comment: I have found a document on the Intel site that says the CrossWalk runtime adds 15-20MB. https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/why-use-crosswalk-for-android-builds